# Jest does not collect coverage from vue files (nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

When I run `jest --coverage` jest only collects coverage from JavaScript files, but not my vue files. The folder structure is correct. `jest.config.js` is in the root folder, just like `/components` and `/lib`. For me, there is no logical explanation why coverage is collected from JavaScript files but not from vue files.

[image]

Here is my `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test-framework-scripts.js'],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue',
    'node',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
  },
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components',
    'shared',
    'test/tmp',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpe?g|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/jest-svg-transform.js',
    '\\.(gql|graphql)$': 'jest-transform-graphql',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(!gsap)',
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue',
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/test/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/test/client/shared-examples/',
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  watchPlugins: [
    'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
    'jest-watch-typeahead/testname',
  ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'components/**/*.{js,vue}',
    'layouts/**/*.{js,vue}',
    'lib/**/*.{js,vue}',
    'middleware/**/*.{js,vue}',
    'mixins/**/*.{js,vue}',
    'pages/**/*.{js,vue}',
    'store/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!<rootDir>/node_modules/**',
    '!<rootDir>/test/**',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'html'],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "stockpicker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a stockpicker",
  "author": "Nico Meyer",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "test.watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.3.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.8.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.11.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-async-computed": "^3.6.1",
    "vue-clickaway2": "^2.3.1",
    "vue2-touch-events": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^0.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.31",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": ">=12.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.11.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": ">=22.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": ">=8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": ">=4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": ">=4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-expect-message": "^1.0.2",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.4.2",
    "jsdom": "^15.1.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.32.0"
  }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: Is it jest 25 version ?

Comment: @Ic3m4n Facing the same issue since yesterday, were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @Aldarund yeah it is. 25.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a regression in jest v25. Nothing can be done at the moment. The issue opened in jest repo https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9490

Comment: this is outdated